# Specify Url in android app

Tags: android

I've searched but can't find the right answer to my question.

Basicly, Im working on a /mobile directory for osTicket.

Instead of http://www.mydomain.com/osticket/mobile being hard coded, I want to be able to change http://www.anotherdomain.com/osticket/mobile or whatever the users url is to the mobile directory.

This is a personal project but I may eventually release the /mobile directory for use with any osTicket install and the app I'm writing but other users of the app will need to be able to provide thier domain so I don't have to customize a copy for each person.

If you have any links, ideas or comments, I would greatly appreciate them..

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want the app user to be able to change the url within the app you should use [Android Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
2. If you want to make it easier to the next developer just create an Env variable

   ```
   public static baseUrl = "http://anydomain.com"; // Put this in a ENV class 
   String urlToUse = baseUrl + "/osticket/mobile/"; // Use it like this when you need
   ```